# Random number guessing game not working C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get this random number guessing game working. The program runs, but it doesn't give the "you won" message when you enter the correct number, and the hint feature does not give the feed back it is supposed to. Any help appreciated.

```
using System;

namespace randomNumberGame
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            var val = r.Next(1, 100);
            var guess = 0;
            bool correct = false;
            var attemptsLeft = 5;
            Console.WriteLine("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.");
            while (!correct && attemptsLeft >=  1)
            { 
                Console.Write("You have " + attemptsLeft + " lives left. Please enter your Guess: ");
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                var message = "";
                var difference = val - guess;
                if (!int.TryParse(input, out guess))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("That's not a number.");
                    continue;
                }
                if (difference == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have won");
                    correct = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Math.Abs(difference) >= 50)
                    {
                        message = Math.Sign(difference) == -1 ? "Very High" : "Very Low";
                    }
                    else if (Math.Abs(difference) < 50 && Math.Abs(difference) >= 20)
                    {
                        message = Math.Sign(difference) == -1 ? "High" : "Low";
                    }
                    else if (Math.Abs(difference) < 20 && Math.Abs(difference) >= 10)
                    {
                        message = Math.Sign(difference) == -1 ? "Moderatley High" : "Moderately Low";
                    }
                    else if (Math.Abs(difference) < 10)
                    {
                        message = Math.Sign(difference) == -1 ? "Somewhat High" : "Somewhat Low";
                    }
                    else Console.WriteLine("???");
                }
                attemptsLeft--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're computing the difference before you parse the guess.

Comment: This is a *great* opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  Using your debugger you can set a breakpoint in the code to pause execution on that line, then step through the code line by line as it executes.  When you do this, you can pause on any line you like, you can observe the behavior of the code live, you can observe the changing values of the variables, etc.  When you do this, what specific line of code first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values at the time?  What result was produced?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: **[Using the free, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** to debug your own code is easier than you think

Comment: Just want to point out that random.Next(1,100) returns a number in the range 1 to 99 - it will never return 100, so the "I'm thinking of.." text is slightly inaccurate. It's fairly inconsequential here, but worth remembering for the next time you use `Next(int,int)`

Comment: Another thing, just in terms of code tidiness, you don't need to check that the number is `>=50` then `< 50 AND >= 20` because if it's greater than 50 then the first if will trigger, so if it gets to the second if the `<50` is already true and doesn't need to be tested. You can hence say `if >=50 .. if >=20 .. if >=10 .. else ..`

Comment: @penno195 You can remove `message` and add `Console.WriteLine` instead. Otherwise I got the won the first time ... but not the 5 times after.

Comment: Thanks everyone, yeah beginner here so I will learn to use the debugger. Problem solved with the Console.WriteLine however I used Console.WriteLine(message) just once before exiting the while loop, This sorted it. 
Some condensation here, be aware not everyone may be aware of debuggers starting out and you are coming here to help no?  All help is appreciated and I hope to be able to pay it forward in a year or two.

Answer (score 1):

> *"it doesn't give the you won message when you enter the correct number"*

Actually, it does! But then the program exits so quickly that you never see it. To solve this, add a line that waits for the user to press a key at the end of your `Main` method, so you can see the final result:

```
// Add this as the last line of the main method:
Console.ReadKey();
```

---

> *"the hint feature does not give the feed back it is supposed too"*

This is because you never output the hint message! At the end of your `while` loop, add a line to do so:

```
// Add this as the last line of the while loop:
Console.WriteLine(message);
```

These things can be found easily if you simply set a breakpoint in your code (in Vistal Studio, click the left margin next to one of the lines and a red dot will appear (or press F9)). Then you can step through the code using `F10` and you can watch the values of local variables change and see what is happening step-by-step.

---

Another way to help avoid problems (and to narrow down where they occur) is to take out chunks of code that does something specific and put it in a method. This will make it easier to debug in the long run.

For example, we can write methods that take in a string to display to the user as a prompt for input, and return a strongly-typed value based on their entry. We can also have these methods take in an optional validation method that can be used to validate that the input they entered falls within a valid range (like a number from 1 to 100, or a name that's not longer than 25 characters):

```
public static string GetStringFromUser(string prompt, 
    Func<string, bool> validator = null)
{
    string result;
    var cursorTop = Console.CursorTop;

    do
    {
        ClearSpecificLineAndWrite(cursorTop, prompt);
        result = Console.ReadLine();
    } while (!(validator?.Invoke(result) ?? true));

    return result;
}

public static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt, 
    Func<int, bool> validator = null)
{
    int result;
    var cursorTop = Console.CursorTop;

    do
    {
        ClearSpecificLineAndWrite(cursorTop, prompt);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) ||
                !(validator?.Invoke(result) ?? true));

    return result;
}

private static void ClearSpecificLineAndWrite(int cursorTop, 
    string message)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, cursorTop);
    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, cursorTop);
    Console.Write(message);
}
```

We can also write a helper method to get our "difference string", which could take in the guess, the number, and the min and max values, then calculate a percentage of how close they were and then return the appropriate string:

```
public static string GetDifferenceString(int guess, int number, 
    int minVal, int maxVal)
{
    var percentAway = 
        Math.Abs(guess - number) / (double)(maxVal - minVal) * 100;
    var direction = guess - number > 0 ? "High" : "Low";

    if (percentAway < 10) return $"Very close, but {direction}";
    if (percentAway < 20) return $"Just a little {direction}";
    if (percentAway < 30) return $"Somewhat {direction}";
    if (percentAway < 40) return $"Moderately {direction}";
    if (percentAway < 50) return $"{direction}";
    return $"Very {direction}";
}
```

This simplifies our main code by removing the loops and checking results from there, and lets us focus on our main tasks:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var randomNumber = new Random().Next(1, 101);
    var maxAttempts = 5;
    var guess = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.");

    for (int attempt = 0; attempt < maxAttempts; attempt++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"You have {maxAttempts - attempt} " + 
            $"out of {maxAttempts} attempts remaining.");

        guess = GetIntFromUser("Please enter your guess (1 - 100): ", 
            i => i > 0 && i < 101);

        if (guess == randomNumber)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"You have won in {attempt + 1} tries!");
            break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(GetDifferenceString(guess, randomNumber, 1, 100));
    }

    if (guess != randomNumber)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you lose! The number was: " + 
            $"{randomNumber}");
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```